# Can't call virtual protected method in derived class

Tags: c++, protected, virtual-functions

The following code does not compile in GCC 4.9.1:

```
class A
{
protected:
   virtual void f() {}

};

class B : public A
{
protected:
   virtual void f() override { A* a = new A; a->f(); }
};
```

I get the following:

```
header.h: In member function 'virtual void B::f()':
header.h:51:17: error: 'virtual void A::f()' is protected
```

I would have expected this to compile.

Why does it fail? Is there a better way than making f() public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A* a = new A; a->f();
```

IS the problem here:
You cannot call `f()` from `a` since it is not `public`, and not accessible to `B` in the member function scope.

---

[It Works!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59b46ff8acc9f965)

Comment: Ok. The strange thing is I could swear I have seen something like this before and it successfully compiled.

Comment: You may have marked `f()` public before... I have added an example anyways

Comment: Maybe. Could it depend from the compiler? I used to use VC++

Comment: Compiling your example on Visual Studio 2015, I get similar errors, compiling on g++ gives similar errors as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure about this either.  I mean, a copy constructor can access protected and private member variables from the object passed as an argument, right?  How else would copy constructors work?  So why can't an object of class A call a protected member function of another object of the same class?

Comment: I guess it's different for inherited classes than for the base class.  Every C++ class is implicitly a friend of itself, but inherited classes are not.

Comment: I understand the rule. However I don't understand why it exists. Where is the harm in calling protected members of some other object of base type? When using virtual functions this could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot *cross-invoke* protected methods between different instances of a class or instances of a parent class just because `B` inherit from that class.

Anyway `B` is already an `A`.
Did you intend to call `A::f();`?

```
class B : public A {
protected:
    virtual void f() override { A::f(); /* ... whatever ... */ }
};
```

Comment: No, not A::f(). Did that behavior change with newer C++ standards?